# Regex remove certain part of an email

Tags: regex, python-re

I'm trying to remove certain parts of an email using regex in python

For instance `john@gmail` can also create `john+1@gmail` `john+sometext@gmail.com` `john+som_et.ext@gmail.com` and so on..

I would like remove the `+1`, `+sometext`, `+som_et.ext` so I'm always left `john@gmail.com`

If I use `([+])\w+` (https://regexr.com/6t7ls) this fails if the email is something like john+som_et.ext@gmail.com

I'm also not totally sure how to convert this to python I have tried the following which does not work

```
REMOVE_PLUS_ADDRESSES = re.compile('([+])\w+/g')

m = REMOVE_PLUS_ADDRESSES.match('asdfasd+asdf@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\+[^\s@]*(?=@)', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cxcqlo/1).

*Details*:

- `\+` - the `+` char
- `[^\s@]*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace and `@`
- `(?=@)` - a location immediately before a `@` char.